# How to loop through file and execute the lines

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, text-processing

I have a text file that contains bash commands for fetching some data from a database. Each command is separated with a newline. See an example below: (the commands could also have been "ls -l", "cat whatever.txt", etc.)

```
prefetch SRR403012
fastq-dump --fasta 0 SRR403012
my_cpp_program.out SRR403012
...
```

How do I create a bash script that executes all these commands?
I want something that executes the command in sequential order. However! It's important to note that the commands will take time before termination, because of the enormous files I am fetching. Thus, the for loop should also wait until the execution has finished.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME="my_commands.txt"
LINES=$(cat $FILENAME)

for LINE in LINES
do
        execute $LINE
done
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't run the file with `bash` ?

Comment: because I'm a noob and don't know how to use bash for it.. Honest answer

Comment: A bash script is a list of commands.

Comment: sourcing the file should do the same result. `source ./my_command.txt` or `. ./my_command.txt` aka dotting in the file. See `help source` or `help .`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your list of commands is effectively a shell script, even without a shebang (the `#!/bin/bash` line at the top). You can specify it as an argument to the shell, and the shell will execute it, one line at a time, waiting for the execution to complete:

```
bash my_commands.txt
```

or, if your commands don’t actually need `bash`,

```
sh my_commands.txt
```

Comment: `source` would be approriate here.

Comment: @glennjackman that makes a number of assumptions about the commands to be run though; `source my_commands.txt` is more likely to produce surprising results for the user than `bash my_commands.txt` (*e.g.* if `my_commands.txt` includes `exit`, or `PATH=...` etc.).

Answer (score 1):

`bash` scripts are

1. executed in order of lines
2. except for if you make it not to

The hashbang `#!/bin/bash` is only necessary if you want to make the file itself an executable and to show which command is meant to interpret the command lines following thereafter.

So all you would need to do is `bash your-command-file`

Check this "command file". Save it as `commands1` and run `bash commands1`

```
echo -n "Hi, "
sleep 1
echo -n "how "
sleep 1
echo -n "are "
sleep 1
echo "you?"
```

And compare to this one (`commands2`):

```
echo -n "Hi, " &
sleep 1 &
echo -n "how " &
sleep 1 &
echo -n "are " &
sleep 1 &
echo "you?"
```

As you can see, in the latter case, the commands are executed more or less in parallel by sending making the commands background processes via `&`.

Comment: I like your answer on the parallel thing. I was wondering if you could look at my question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/639914/how-to-run-a-bash-script-using-threads. Here, I want to run it in parallel

Comment: @GoldenRetriever done, suggesting GNU parallel there.